# Загрузить данные из файла csv

Tags: python-3.x, django, python-3.6

Пытаюсь загрузить данные из файла Station-2018-12-16.csv, но ничего не получается. 
Выполнял приведенный ниже код(это только его часть, если потребуется добавлю весь код из представления) в Visual Studio всё работало, вставил его в представление в django, в результате пришел к выводу, что данные из Station-2018-12-16.csv не подгружаются. Может в django не достаточно вставить файл, может надо ещё что-то, где-то прописать? Файл находится в то же директории где и station_list.html Ниже добавил картинки с директориями в Django и Visual Studio.

```
<script>
...
var csvLayer = new CSVLayer({
   url: "Station-2018-12-16.csv", //задаем путь к файлу
   copyright: "USGS Earthquakes",
   popupTemplate: template,
   elevationInfo: {
   // drapes icons on the surface of the globe
      mode: "on-the-ground"
                  }
            });
...
<script>
```

[image: Visual Studio]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Забыл, что в django всё по другому. Создал каталог static и уже оттуда всё подгрузил, [здесь](https://metanit.com/python/django/2.2.php) всё показано на примере css файла.